# I'm not able to resolve this routing issue of my react app after successfully deploying on vercel

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

i'm deploying my app through github on vercel

here's the link:
[website](https://temp-five-eta.vercel.app/)
on top right corner there's a **Navigate** button, it redirects to a different route but if you referesh the page it says 404 not found, same thing is happening in netlify, i'm thinking it has something to do with my vite configuration, i don't know :/

vite config:

```
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
  server: {
    port: 4000,
  },
});
```

vite docs says not need for base:"/", which is by default.

main.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "@mantine/core/styles.css";
import "@mantine/carousel/styles.css";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-authbox";
import { theme } from "@/configs/theme.ts";
import { MantineProvider } from "@mantine/core";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MantineProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider fetchUserUrl="http://localhost:3000/api/user">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    </MantineProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

app.tsx:

```
import Routes from "@/routes/routes";

const App = () => <Routes />;

export default App;
```

Routes.tsx:

```
import AddBusinessInformationPage from "@/pages/client/addbusinessinformationpage";
import SelectCategoriesPage from "@/pages/client/selectcategoriespage";
import ProfileSetingsPage from "@/pages/client/profilesettingspage";
import { FormProvider } from "@/providers/formprovider";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ClientLayout from "@/components/layouts";
import HomePage from "@/pages/client/homepage";
import { FC } from "react";

const RoutesComponent: FC = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          <FormProvider>
            <ClientLayout />
          </FormProvider>
        }
      >
        <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="profile-settings" element={<ProfileSetingsPage />} />
        <Route path="select-category" element={<SelectCategoriesPage />} />
        <Route
          path="/add-business-information"
          element={<AddBusinessInformationPage />}
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default RoutesComponent;
```

i tried base: "/" which is by default.

Comment: Which route is it that fails? If it's `/add-bussiness-information` maybe try removing the `/`.

Comment: all three of them > https://temp-five-eta.vercel.app/ refresh the page

Comment: the navigate button redirects to "select-category" route which doesn't have a "/"

Comment: local build server is running fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the `verce.json` file:

```
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

To redirect all the request to root destination where index.html is located which renders the main.tsx, the routing is handled by the client.

Each platform require there own way of re-write config.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you change how you nest your routes and add a [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router).

```
const RoutesComponent: FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<FormProvider/>}
          >
            <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="profile-settings" element={<ProfileSetingsPage />} />
            <Route path="select-category" element={<SelectCategoriesPage />} />
            <Route
              path="add-business-information"
              element={<AddBusinessInformationPage />}
            />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Please also check if your Link is correct.

Comment: thanks for your valuable time, still nothing even after adding the browser router directly to in the routes folder, upon refreshing 404, btw i'm using vite swc from the prompt perhaps that rings any bell

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem. The other pages except for the home page always gave the 'code not found' error on reload. Adding a vercel.json file in the project directory with the following lines solved the problem.

> `{ "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }] }`